# Fixed frame in HTML

Tags: ajax, html

I'm creating a AJAX based detail system where details are visible in **onmouseover** event, for this I created following HTML to display

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <Script src="scripts/ajaxfunctions.js"></Script>
        </head>
        <body>
          <table widht="1000">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/0.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(0)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
                <td rowspan="8" width="500">
                    <div id="myDiv" ></div>
                </td>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/1.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(1)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/2.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(2)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/3.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(3)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/4.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(4)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/5.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(5)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/6.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(6)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/7.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(7)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/8.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(8)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/9.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(9)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/10.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(7)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/11.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(7)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/12.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(7)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/13.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(7)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/14.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(7)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/15.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(7)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/16.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(7)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/17.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(7)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/18.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(7)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/19.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(7)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/20.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(7)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/21.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(7)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/22.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(7)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/23.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(7)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/24.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(7)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/24.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(7)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/25.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(7)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <img src="Images/26.jpg" width="100" height="100" onmouseover="func(7)" onmouseout="clear()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
     </body>
</html>
```

in here the details will be shown in div tag.... but when the entries in left hand side expands the content in DIV tag is not visible... have scroll up to see the details... are there any way to fix the right hand side div in to the screen?

Javascript code is here

```
    function func(num)
        {
            var xmlhttp;
            var txt,x,xx,i;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {       // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    txt="";
                    try
                    {
                        var xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
                        txt="";
                        var a = 0;
                        x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Person");
                        var xx= x[num].getElementsByTagName("Name");
                        txt += "Name : " + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue+ "<br>" ;
                        xx = x[num].getElementsByTagName("RegistrationNO");
                        txt += "RegistrationNo : " + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue+ "<br>" ;
                        xx = x[num].getElementsByTagName("Address");
                        txt += "Address : " + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue+ "<br>" ;
                        xx= x[num].getElementsByTagName("ContactNo");
                        txt += "Contact No : " + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue+ "<br>";
                        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=txt;
                    }
                    catch (er)
                    {
                        document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML=er+" 1";
                    }

                }
            }   
            try
            {
            xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/StudentDetails/Data/database.xml",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            }
            catch (er)
            {
                document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML=er+" 2";
            }
        }
```

Comment: To lessen the code and make it quicker you can assign a class to each image (like '.image') and then in jQuery do a mouseover and mouseout on the class so that you don't have to write 26 times the same code. Look here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ and here http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: Is there a CSS code with this? can you give us a JSFiddle or actual link to see the problem? Also post the javascript code, not only html please.

Comment: Question is edited...., and how the HTML can do this with less coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is you can use `position: fixed` in CSS to place your div where you want it, and have it not move when the rest of the page scrolls.

If that doesn't work for you, you could use javascript to position the div in the vicinity of the image that triggered the mouseover event so it will within view.

I put together a demo using jQuery, this can all be done with straight javascript, I like the compact look of jQuery

[position: fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/FxVfT/1/)
[position: absolute](http://jsfiddle.net/FxVfT/) - snap to image
[position: absolute](http://jsfiddle.net/FxVfT/2/) - snap to screen

I changed some other things for the demo as well:

I usually try to avoid tables, I find div's to be easier to use in most situations.  I would suggest 3 divs, a div to hold the pictures, the div to display the data, and an outer div to contain and align the other two:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id='pictures'></div>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</div>
```

If your image names are really as predictable as your example, you can generate all the image tags on the fly:

```
$(function () {
    for (i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
        $("div#pictures").append("<img id='" + i + "' class='studentimg' src='Images/" + i + ".jpg' />");
        $(".studentimg").on('mouseover', function (e) {func(this);}).on('mouseout', clear);
    }
});
```

Then Couple that with some CSS:

```
div#outer {
    position: relative;
}
div#myDiv {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    left: 135px;
}
div#pictures {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
}
img.studentimg {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

I also notice that you are reloading the data for all of the people every time you mouse over any one of the images.  I think it may be more efficient to load the list when the page loads, and have the text pre-built.

Re-using your code (it could also be condensed with jQuery), define and populate an array:

```
var peopleList = Array();

function fetchXML() {
    var xmlhttp;
    var txt, x, xx, i;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            txt = "";
            try {
                var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Person");
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    txt = "";
                    var xx = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name");
                    txt += "Name : " + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "<br>";
                    xx = x[num].getElementsByTagName("RegistrationNO");
                    txt += "RegistrationNo : " + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "<br>";
                    xx = x[num].getElementsByTagName("Address");
                    txt += "Address : " + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "<br>";
                    xx = x[num].getElementsByTagName("ContactNo");
                    txt += "Address : " + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "<br>";
                    peopleList[i] = txt;
                }
            } catch (er) {
                peopleList[i] = er + " 1";
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/StudentDetails/Data/database.xml", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    } catch (er) {
        peopleList = null;
        document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = er + " 2";
    }
}
```

so at mouseover time, all you have to do is display the text:

```
function func(el) {
    $("#myDiv").html(peopleList[el.id]);
}
```

Comment: can you give me the full html file... I have some trouble in concatenating it

Comment: The HTML was only 4 lines, the CSS would go in your stylesheet, and the rest would go in your javascript file.